# Antlr4 create additional output file for custom target language

Tags: matlab, antlr4, target

I am trying to build a custom target for antlr4 (i.e. Matlab). Thereofore I looked at the built-in target languages of the project and found out that the generated parser file XXParser.xx contains two classes i.e. parser AND context. This is not supported by Matlab. Only one class per file is allowed.

Therefore I tried the following:

1. I created a new ContextFile.java under .../codegen/model
2. I added the following lines to the Matlab.stg file:

   ```
   ContextFile(file, header, namedActions,funcs) ::= <<
   <fileHeader(file.grammarFileName, file.ANTLRVersion)>    
   # encoding: utf-8        

   <namedActions.header>    

   Hello Context    

   >>
   ```
3. I successfully compiled and successfully built the Hello.g4 example. Unfortunately creating the additional file failed.

How can I force the tool to output the additional file?

Thanks, 
Daniel

Comment: Matlab relies on an externally supplied JDK to create standard  `.class` files accessible through its Java call interface. No evident limitation to only one class per file.  The context classes are inner classes. Should be able to use standard Java reference semantics to import: `import <packageName>.<outerclassName>.<innerclassName>;`.

Comment: GRosenberg, thanks for the quick reply! I understand that you recommend not implementing a full Matlab target environment but rather stick as much as possible with the Java implementation. Is this correct? Thanks, Daniel